# How do i rdesktop from Kali Linux to Windows xp and display on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, windows-xp, remote-desktop, kali-linux

I am on a windows 10 laptop. I am SSHing into a Kali GNU/Linux (has a public IP, and an IP in a LAN) (no root privileges). I am trying to remote desktop into a Windows XP computer (On the LAN, no public IP, no ssh).

I've already gotten onto the windows XP computer with msfconsole got the administrator username and password and `run post/windows/manage/enable_rdp` (I think this enables remote desktop). when I run `rdesktop -u {adminuser] -p {adminpassword}` from the Kali I get the error `UI(error): ui_init(), failed to open X11 display:`.

I think the problem here is that the Kali computer doesn't have a screen or something like that, but I am not sure. How do I set this up so I can remote desktop into the windows xp computer, seeing/interacting with the screen from my windows 10 laptop?

If not having root on the kali computer is a big problem, I could ssh from the kali computer to another computer running `Linux kali 5.15.0-kali2-amd64 SMP Debian 5.15.5-2kali2` (also on the LAN, no public IP) where I have root privileges then rdesktop to the windows XP

Please note that this is the most complicated thing I've done on the command line by far, so please don't assume I know random terms.

Comment: If RDP is enabled and running on XP, why not rdp in directly from the windows 10 machine? What do you expect to see over an SSH connection?

Comment: If you need to use RDP *through* the kali box, you can use SSH to port-forward RDP traffic to the XP machine via https://serverfault.com/questions/200249/how-to-tunnel-windows-remote-desktop-through-ssh-using-a-linux-box

Comment: The problem isn't exactly Kali doesn't have a "screen", but ssh. You can't just ssh in a host and try to run a GUI program and expect it to show up on the host you ssh from, at least not without setting up X11Forwarding whatsover. You can set up a vnc server or so on your Kali and then vnc in though, or if it's really just about networking, set up a VPN (or use an ssh tunnel that provides a somewhat similar functionality).

Comment: the kali Computer I originally ssh into has a public IP and is part of a LAN. all the other computers are on that LAN. I should have mentioned this in my post. I've fixed it now.

Comment: @hutonahill You have the extra option of DNAT (a.k.a. port forwarding; not the ssh kind though) then.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I tried the solutions offered on that serverfault.com page, but they didn't work. I don't know if I just misunderstood how to use them. I ran the command ssh -L 13389:{win-xp-adress}:3389 {myuser}@{kali-ip} and it opened an ssh connection. i then ran the rdekstop command and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the problem here is that the Kali computer doesn't have a screen or something like that, but I am not sure.

It's not that the computer doesn't have a screen – it's the *SSH connection* that doesn't have one. Your SSH session is only set up to transport text (a terminal session) and on its own cannot make a graphical window pop up.

- SSH *can* transport X11 graphics, but you'll need additional software: an "X11 server" running on your local machine, to actually render them on screen. For Windows, there are several options of varying quality (VcxSrv, Xming, X410, the Cygwin one, the one in MobaXterm...). After you've installed and launched an X11 server, connect to Kali with SSH X11 forwarding enabled:

  ```
  PS>  $env:DISPLAY = "localhost:0"
  PS>  ssh kali_address -C -Y
  ```

  Within that SSH session, an X11 display should now be available for graphical programs. (It won't be nearly as fast as RDP or VNC; although X11 was once made for network use, it was made for network use with very different UIs.)
- Easier and more reliable alternative: Instead of rdesktop on Kali, run the Remote Desktop client on your local machine and use SSH to tunnel the RDP TCP connection. This doesn't need any additional software – just add the `-L` option to your SSH connection:

  ```
  PS>  ssh kali_address -L 3390:winxp_address:3389
  ```

  As long as this SSH session is running, it will be listening on localhost:3390 for connections (which will be forwarded to the RDP server).

Comment: I tried your second method. Here's what I think should happen: I run the command `PS>  ssh kali_address -L 3390:winxp_address:3389` on my windows 10 computer swapping out the relevant addresses the command says that when the win XP sends data from its 3389 port it should send it to my win10 3390 port. Then I run the `rdesktop` command in the kali ssh connection and it opens a remote desktop on my win 10.  What actually happens is I get the same X11 error.

Comment: You missed the "*Instead of* rdesktop on Kali..."

Comment: am i inputing the kali_address, the winxp_adress or localhost:3390 into the remote desktop client?

Comment: also, in the command, there's the line `3390:winxp_adress:3389` what is the purpose of each if these numbers? which of these numbers is referring to the port on the WinXP and which is the port on win10?

Comment: `3390` (which is short for `localhost:3390` in this situation) is the listening port on the SSH client side (i.e. Win10), while `winxp_address:3389` is the connect address from the SSH server side (i.e. Kali). Whenever the SSH client receives a connection at localhost:3390, it will ask the server to connect to winxp_address:3389 and forward the data back and forth.